# Insert an icon in menu item that uses an user defined Template

Tags: wpf, menuitem

I want to have a dropdown menu with custom background color of the menu item. I was able to achieve this with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24699287/12526953). The root menu item in my GUI has only an icon with no `Header`. The code I used to define the menu item icon is as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuIcon" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                 <Menu Background="Orange">
                     <MenuItem ToolTip="Menu" BorderBrush="White">
                          <MenuItem.Header>
                               <StackPanel
                                   Width="60"
                                   Height="50"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Background="Orange"
                                   Orientation="Horizontal">
                                   <Viewbox
                                       Margin="9"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Stretch="Fill">
                                       <Grid Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                                          <Path
                                              x:Name="MenuIconFillStyle"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              Data="M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM615v-3h36v3Z"
                                              Fill="White" />
                                       </Grid>
                                   </Viewbox>
                               </StackPanel>
                           </MenuItem.Header>
                        </MenuItem>
                     </Menu>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                             <Setter TargetName="MenuIconFillStyle" Property="Fill" Value="Yellow" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

I added the following in the `<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">` taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24699287/12526953):

```
 <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
```

and the following in the `ControlTemplate.Triggers`:

```
<Trigger Property="Icon" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Visible"/>
</Trigger>
```

The `Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"` is as  follows:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Border x:Name="templateRoot" 
                    BorderBrush="#535353" 
                    CornerRadius="3" 
                    BorderThickness="1" 
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="26" Height="16" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"  AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" HorizontalOffset="-2">
                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#595959" BorderThickness="1" Background="#3A3A3A" Padding="2">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource DarkBrush}"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#2C2C2C"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="1"></Setter>
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Clicked}" />
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Test" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#2C2C2C"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

The custom background and the icon for the `MenuItem` is specified as in the following code snippet:

```
<Grid Background="#535353">
    <Menu Width="100" Height="22" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
    </Menu>
</Grid>
```

The icon defined in `Style` is not rendering in the `MenuItem` along with the Template (`Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"`) used for setting the background color. How can this be achieved?

**Edit**

Based on the suggestion of @mm8, I tried to combine the Styles that are responsible for changing the background color (The Style with `x:Key="TopLevelHeaderStyle"` which is borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61133549/12526953)) and inserting a menu item icon in the root menu and came up with the following:

```
 <Style x:Key="TopLevelHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#000d18"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d8d8d8"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="72"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="42"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="MenuItemBorder" Width="72" Height="42" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MenuItemBorder}"
                                   HorizontalOffset="1" VerticalOffset="-1">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#414141" Background="#414141">
                                        <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                        </ScrollViewer>
                                    </Border>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1271C8"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--MenuIcon-->
        <Style x:Key="MenuIcon" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource TopLevelHeaderStyle}">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                        <Menu>
                            <MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem.Header>
                                    <StackPanel
                            Width="60"
                            Height="50"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Background="Orange"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Viewbox
                                Margin="9"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Stretch="Fill">
                                            <Grid Margin="-8,0,0,0">
                                                <Path x:Name="MenuIconFillStyle"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Fill="White"              
                                        Data="M6 36v-3h36v3Zm0-10.5v-3h36v3ZM6 15v-3h36v3Z"
                                       />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Viewbox>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </MenuItem.Header>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
```

And used it as follows:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Menu Grid.Column="0" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem  Header="File" Style="{StaticResource TopLevelHeaderStyle}">
                <MenuItem Header="New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Close"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <Menu Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <MenuItem Margin="-11, 0,0,0" Width="50" Header="File" Style="{StaticResource MenuIcon}">
                <MenuItem Header="New1"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Open1"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Close1"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
```

Now the drop down menu having an icon in the root menu item is not showing the other menu item contents `New1`, `Open1` and `Close1`  What mistake am I making?

Comment: What exact template are you using? Where is the `ContentPresenter` in your example? What's the purpose of the template, i.e. what results are you expecting?

Comment: @ mm8, My end goal is to have a drop down menu that has 1) only the Icon in the root menu item and 2) custom background color. I am able to achieve the first goal. To achieve the second goal I used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24699287/12526953). The Icon disappears when I set the background color using the Template

Comment: So which template are you currently using?

Comment: `Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"`

Comment: I am using that template to change the background color of drop down menu. I have provided the link from where I found. Now I have added the template to my question.

Comment: Since you can only one one template, you are not using the `MenuIcon` style at all then? Why is the style then included in the question at all. It just makes it confusing.

Comment: Style is used to insert the icon in the root menu item and template is used to change the background color of the drop down menu

Comment: No. Again, there can only be *one* template applied. The one in your style *or* `MenuItemControlTemplate1`.

Comment: I am new to WPF. Can you please suggest how to achieve what I want? Can I change the background color in the Style itself?

Comment: You need to merge templates into one that fits both your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The MenuItem control has a DependencyProperty of type Object named 'Icon'. This property is reserved for your exact purpose.

First you need to bind the Data in the Path within your MenuItem ControlTemplate  to the Icon property of the parent MenuItem. Like this:

```
<Path x:Name="MenuIconFillStyle"
   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
   VerticalAlignment="Center"
   Data="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
   Fill="White" />
```

Now you may specify a PathGeometry in XAML like this. Its contents will be your SVG data:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="MySpecialPath">M2 0C0.89687</PathGeometry>
```

Finally, apply this path using its Key to any MenuItem as a StaticResource:

```
<Menu Width="100" Height="22" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <MenuItem Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"
              Icon="{StaticResource MySpecialPath}">
</Menu>
```

If you want a bit more control out of your icons (multiple colors, different size, margin, etc..) It is a bit more involved. Just remember that the 'Path' property on MenuItem is an Object so you can hypothetically use any 'Presenting' element (Does not need to be Path) in your MenuItem ControlTemplate and TemplateBind it to MenuItem.Path - then pass any type of 'Presented' object to the MenuItem (does not need to be PathGeometry). You can look into using a

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" />
```

instead of the Path control in the MenuItem ControlTemplate - and then giving literally any "Icon" control to your MenuItem.Path property in your XAML.

Comment: @ purquhart, I modified the code as per your suggestions. The Icon vanishes when I use the template (`Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}"`) to use custom background color for the drop down menu items. Can you please help me fix this?

Comment: I didn't see that you were setting the style and template on the MenuItem separately. I'm not sure this is exactly what you want to do here, you just need to set the Style on a MenuItem instance. Here is what needs to happen for my suggestion to work. 1. Define a Style Targeting MenuItem with a Key. 2. Set the 'Template' property of the style to a ControlTemplate Targeting MenuItem (this is what you did in your first code block). 3. Within that ControlTemplate use a Path with {TemplateBinding Icon} like I showed you. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) 4. When you declare an instance of a MenuItem, set its 'Style' property as a StaticResrouce to the Key from step 1. Set its 'Icon' property as a StaticResrouce to a PathGeometry you defined. If you want a MenuItem Style with Template that you are sure is correct, use this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 . Then you can try following my steps.

Comment: The Styles and ControlTemplates are hard to wrap your head around fully, but once you see the bigger picture you will understand. I really do recommend taking this example from Microsoft and typing it all out yourself to see what is going on / making your own visual adjustments, then trying to add the Icon property.

Comment: Can we specify both Styles as well as ControlTemplates for the MenuItem? If yes, can you help me with the syntax?